# Problema ao recuperar 2 valores com javascript e jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com o problema para recuperar 2 valores e enviar pelo load. Eu consigo  recuperar os dados do link do atributo 'data' mas do input não consigo recuperar para concatenar com o 'data' e fazer o caminho certo.
Segue o código.

Javascript:

```
$('.buscarr').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('campo1');
    var id2 = $(this).attr('data');
    alert(id);
    console.log(id);
    console.log(id2);
    $("#cliente1").load($(this).attr(id2 + id));
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="busca">Nome Servico*:</label> <input id="campo1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira um nome para busca">
</div>
<a href="#" data="/wbahd/servico_servlet?acao=buscar&busca=" class="btn btn-default btn-cadastrar-btn buscarr">Buscar</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Não entendi, se você já sabe o `id`, por que buscar pelo valor de `id`? O que você pretende armazenar aqui: `var id = $(this).attr('campo1');`?

Comment: o valor do campo é concatenar com outro valor.

Comment: Mas só que aqui var id = $(this).attr('campo1'); não me retorna nada.

Comment: Não retorna nada porque `attr` busca por um atributo do elemento, e `buscarr` não o tem.

Comment: Tinha tentado com atributo tmb é nada , ai voltei para o id.Continua me retornando 'undefined'.

Comment: Obg consegui recuperar o valor do id mas não consigo fazer o load concatenando $("#cliente1").load($(this).attr(id2+id)); sera pq ?.Estou tentando aqui de outras formas mas nada tmb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não retorna nada porque attr busca por um atributo do elemento, e buscarr não o tem. – Lucas Costa

Use   `var id = var id = $('#campo1').val();`   ou  `var id = $('form-control').val();`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.buscarr').click(function() {
    var id = $('#campo1').val();
    //var id = $('form-control').val();
    var id2 = $(this).attr('data');
    //alert(id);
    console.log(id);
    console.log(id2);
    //$("#cliente1").load($(this).attr(id2 + id));
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="busca">Nome Servico*:</label> <input id="campo1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira um nome para busca">
</div>
<a href="#" data="/wbahd/servico_servlet?acao=buscar&busca=" class="btn btn-default btn-cadastrar-btn buscarr">Buscar</a>

</div>
```

Também pode usar  `var id = document.getElementById('campo1').value;`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.buscarr').click(function() {
    var id = document.getElementById('campo1').value;
    var id2 = $(this).attr('data');
    //alert(id);
    console.log(id);
    console.log(id2);
    //$("#cliente1").load($(this).attr(id2 + id));
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="busca">Nome Servico*:</label> <input id="campo1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira um nome para busca">
</div>
<a href="#" data="/wbahd/servico_servlet?acao=buscar&busca=" class="btn btn-default btn-cadastrar-btn buscarr">Buscar</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Leo obg. Mas estou tentando fazer o load é não estou conseguindo, fiz esse trecho de código $("#cliente1").load('/wbahd/servico_servlet?acao=buscar&busca='+id); ele faz a ação pega o parâmetro  mas não faz o load da página.

Comment: editei a resposta, acho que um deles vai te servir

Comment: nada ainda eu preciso fazer o load da pargina

Comment: aí já é outro problema, que merece outra pergunta para que a resposta/comentários referentes a pergunta atual não fique sem sentido